# увеличить количество немодальных окон JS. При добавлении одинаковых блоков работает только одно окно, как сделать так чтобы работали оба, и сделать 5

Tags: javascript, html, css

```js
dragElement(document.getElementById(("mydiv")));

function dragElement(elmnt) {
  var pos1 = 0,
    pos2 = 0,
    pos3 = 0,
    pos4 = 0;
  if (document.getElementById(elmnt.id + 'header')) {
    document.getElementById(elmnt.id + 'header').onmousedown = dragMouseDown;
  } else {
    elmnt.onmousedown = dragMouseDown;
  }

  function dragMouseDown(e) {
    e = e || window.event;
    pos3 = e.clientX;
    pos4 = e.clientY;
    document.onmouseup = closeDragElement;
    document.onmousemove = elementDrag;
  }

  function elementDrag(e) {
    e = e || window.event;
    pos1 = pos3 - e.clientX;
    pos2 = pos4 - e.clientY;
    pos3 = e.clientX;
    pos4 = e.clientY;
    elmnt.style.top = (elmnt.offsetTop - pos2) + "px";
    elmnt.style.left = (elmnt.offsetLeft - pos1) + "px";
  }

  function closeDragElement() {
    document.onmouseup = null;
    document.onmousemove = null;
  }
}




function closePopup() {
  this.closest('#mydiv').style.display = 'none';
}

let elements = document.querySelectorAll('.popup-close');

for (let e of elements) {
  e.addEventListener('click', closePopup);
}
```

```css
#mydiv {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 9;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid #d3d3d3;
}

#mydivheader {
  padding: 10px;
  cursor: move;
  z-index: 10;
  background-color: #2196f3;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Modal Window</title>
</head>

<body>
  <h1>Draggable DIV Element</h1>
  <p>Click and hold the mouse button down while moving the DIV Element</p>

  <div id="mydiv">
    <div id="mydivheader">
      <button class="popup-close" type="button"><span class="hidden"><font color="#fff">Х</font></span> </button>
      <font color="black"> Click here to move</font>

    </div>
    <p>Move</p>
    <p>This</p>
    <p>DIV</p>
  </div>

  <div id="mydiv">
    <div id="mydivheader">
      <button class="popup-close" type="button"><span class="hidden"><font color="#fff">Х</font></span> </button>
      <font color="black"> Click here to move</font>

    </div>
    <p>Move</p>
    <p>This</p>
    <p>DIV</p>
  </div>




</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Сперва, замените получение модальных окон с ID на получение через class
Сохранить их список:

```js
const modals = [...document.getElementsByClassName("<имя класса>")];
```

Примените функцию dragElement ко всем элементам, по сути как вы и делали до этого:

```js
modals.forEach(dragElement);
```

Внутри `dragElement` также откажитесь от обращения по айди в пользу получения потомка по известному классу:

```js
const className = "mydiv-header" // Для примера
elmnt.querySelector(`.${ className `);
```